# how to Update ListView after deletion

Tags: android-studio, listview

Here I'm using Custom Adapter by implementing listAdapter to Support buttons in the list items. When i click the Delete button it deletes currect row. But i can't able to refresh this listView.

File Structure is  MainActivity -> FragmentClass-> this Custom class for the listAdpater.

```
public class Category_ListView_Custom_Adapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter{

private Realm realm;
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

public Category_ListView_Custom_Adapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context){
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return list.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view1 = view;
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    if(view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_listview_row, null);
    }
    TextView listItemText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item);
    listItemText.setText(list.get(i));

    ImageView edit = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    ImageView delete = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete);

    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
     //       list.remove(i);
     ///       Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "hey "+list.get(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     //       notifyDataSetChanged();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddCategory.class);
            intent.putExtra("category","expense");
            intent.putExtra("subcategory", list.get(i));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            RealmResults<Category> categorylist = realm.where(Category.class).equalTo("Id",i+1).and().equalTo("Subcategory",list.get(i)).findAll();

            for (Category category : categorylist) {

                realm.beginTransaction();
                categorylist.deleteFirstFromRealm();
                realm.commitTransaction();

                try {
                    context.notifyAll();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

             //   Expense.call_resume
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

Please Help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please use RecyclerView

Comment: use notify to update the data.

Answer (score 0):

You are .removing from a wrong view. Try to make root List<> static and do Class.list.get(i).remove or something like that.

Also, try to hide a view inside your get view.

Comment: ok But how can i get Fragment class instance to remove. when i try i am facing error.

Comment: So doubt is, how to pass class instance from Fragment class to base class.